# How can I get 3D transitions for LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice

I have installed LibreOffice 5 using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

However in Impress the 3D transitions (eg Rochade) are not installed.  I've used Ubuntu for years, and seem to remember this had something to do with OpenGL. How can I get these transitions on elementary OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing the transitions by running `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-ogltrans` in terminal. The transitions should be installed

Comment: @MattB The bounty???

Comment: Sorry,  new to stack exchange.  What do I do?

Comment: @MattB Daniel Fore opened a bounty